# ベン図を書いた時のAかつBかつCとなる行のみを抽出したい

Tags: python, r

```
>list_A.txt
ID_1    1.00    8.00
ID_5    3.00    5.00
ID_8    2.00    0.00
>list_B.txt
ID_1    1.00    8.00
ID_3    3.00    5.00
ID_8    2.00    1.00
ID_9    5.00    2.00
>list_C.txt
ID_2    1.00    8.00
ID_3    3.00    5.00
ID_8    3.00    0.00
```

上記のようなリストから、全てに共通するもの（ID_8）のみを取り出したいです。

```
>list_A.txt
ID_8    2.00    0.00
>list_B.txt
ID_8    2.00    1.00
>list_C.txt
ID_8    3.00    0.00
```

これまでは、Rのvenn関数でベン図を書き、A[A[,1] %in% C[,1]]でAとCに共通なIDを取り出し、そのIDを元にコマンドラインでjoinしていました。
しかし、この方法だとあまりにも煩雑なので、pythonもしくはRを使用し一括処理したいと思うのですが、方法が全く思いつきません。

なにかアドバイスをいただけませんでしょうか。よろしくお願いします。

Comment: ファイルの数は固定ですか。それとも任意の数のファイルを扱う必要がありますか

Comment: ファイル数は任意の数です。
Pythonのセット型を利用して処理を行おうと思ったのですが、globですべてのファイルを読み込んだものの、それぞれのファイルでリスト化する方法が分からずに再び詰まってしまいました。
引き続き、アドバイスをいただければと思います。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rでの例です。

```
### データ作成
library(tidyverse)

list_A <-
  data.frame(id = c("ID_1", "ID_5", "ID_8"),
             value1 = c(1, 3, 2), value2 = c(8, 5, 0), file = "A")
list_B <-
  data.frame(id = c("ID_1", "ID_3", "ID_8", "ID_9"),
             value1 = c(1, 3, 2, 5), value2 = c(8, 5, 1, 2), file = "B")
list_C <-
  data.frame(id = c("ID_2", "ID_3", "ID_8"),
             value1 = c(1, 3, 3), value2 = c(8, 5, 0), file = "C")

input <- list(list_A, list_B, list_C)
input <- lapply(file_paths, function(path) mutate(read_csv(path), file = path)) # ファイルパスから一括読み込みする

### 処理
selected <- Reduce(intersect, map(input, "id"))
filter(bind_rows(input), id %in% selected)

### 結果
# 　　 id value1 value2 file
# 1 ID_8      2      0    A
# 2 ID_8      2      1    B
# 3 ID_8      3      0    C
```

Answer (score 0):

セット型を使えば良いかと思います。

```
a = [("ID10",10,20),("ID20",30,40),("ID30",50,60)]
b = [("ID11",11,21),("ID21",31,41),("ID30",51,61)]
c = [("ID12",12,22),("ID22",32,42),("ID30",52,62)]

#先頭行(ID)を抽出
for i in a:
    a1.append(i[0])    
for i in b:
    b1.append(i[0])
for i in c:
    c1.append(i[0])

#先頭行(ID)をset型に変更
a1_set = set(a1)
b1_set = set(b1)
c1_set = set(c1)

#共通のIDを抽出
comID = a1_set & b1_set & c1_set

#共通のIDのデータを抽出
for ID in comID:
    for i in a:
        if ID == i[0]:
            print(i)
    for i in b:
        if ID == i[0]:
            print(i)
    for i in c:
        if ID == i[0]:
            print(i)
```

結果は以下です。

```
('ID30', 50, 60)
('ID30', 51, 61)
('ID30', 52, 62)
```